# How can I fix virus-infected USB flash drive using my Android (via USB otg)?

Tags: usb-on-the-go, antivirus

My USB flash drive was **plugged into an infected PC**, and now it contains viruses. Actually, that flash drive was filled with stuff I wanted to transfer to my Android. So I decided to use that flash drive on my phone anyway (via otg) considering those PC viruses would not affect an Android. It went well in the beginning, I transferred files successfully, but now the **flash drive shows size 0 bytes when I connect it to phone**.
Is there any app that could help me? 
My phone is sadly **non rooted** and I can't root it without PC I guess.

Comment: Did you try formatting it?

Comment: I still had some files on it which I needed....

Comment: You can try recovering them later

Comment: I decided to get it to a PC after finding no solution. So should I delete this question or let it stay here?

Comment: Let it stay. May be someone some days will find a solution